# UIStackView issue with Distribution

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am facing an issue with UIStackview distribution. I did horizontal UIStackView with `align center` and `Fill Proportionally` distribution. But I am not getting the exact result as per the attached image.

Here I attached xcode adaptive layout and output on the simulator image. the right and left are UIViews and it contains only background color and the center has UILabel with text. So how the intrinsic content size will work for empty UIViews and how can we achieve this?

[**Xcode adaptive layout image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVBlp.png)

[**iPhone 12 Pro max output image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8eID.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the relevant code and a screenshot of what you are actually getting.

Comment: Also for a horizontal stack view note that the alignment property controls the vertical alignment of elements, not the horizontal alignment.

Comment: @shim I updated screenshots and question please check it. here main problem with UIView intrinsic content size for UIViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the expected output you should be using `Fill` distribution instead of "Fill proportionally". Then, making both side views to have the same width should solve the issue:

```
    let leftSideView = UIView()
    leftSideView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    leftSideView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let rightSideView = UIView()
    rightSideView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    rightSideView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(leftSideView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(rightSideView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        leftSideView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightSideView.widthAnchor)
    ])
```

The end result should be this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9NHP.png)

Also, there is no need to add a fixed/constant width to the Hello text because UILabels already have an intrinsic content size. This will also make your UI more future-proof: You might want to localize your app in the future and the "Hello" text will be larger or shorter depending on the language.

Comment: I tried it but here the main problem is left and right are UIViews are just having background colors but not any subviews. see attached image links [xcode adaptive layout] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVBlp.png) and [output] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8eID.png)

Comment: @Kingdom Why not add a subview for the dividers? Each of your subviews can contain a view with a height of 1pt approximately, you pin that subview to the horizontal edges of its parent view and center it vertically. That should be enough to achieve your expected output. Alternatively, you can also draw those dividers inside the two views instead of adding new subviews.

Comment: Not working. it is not working. Can you please try at your end.

Comment: @Kingdom I created a sample project. Take a look at it: https://github.com/DeluxeAlonso/StackOverflowSampleProject

Comment: @Kingdom I just faced the same issue you were having. You are right, Fill proportionally was not working. The approach I used to achieve your expected design was to use a Fill distribution and I also created a constraint so both side views would have the same width. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Now it is working thank you.